# sed: how to replace sth. by a backslash followed by reference

Tags: batch-file, sed, backslash

Despite all the *sed-backslash* discussions on Stackoverflow I cannot find a working solution for my specific problem. I want to precede a certain string in a file by a backslash: `something -> \something`.

```
sed -i -- 's/\(something\)/\\\1/g' file
```

This always returns the string `\1` instead of `\something`, because for some reason sed thinks it should escape the third backslash. The (from my point of view more logical) behaviour can be achieved by inserting a space between `\\` and `\1` in the sed command, but then the result is `\ something` (i.e. with an inserted space in the result) which is not what I want.

I am running this command in a batch file on Windows, using `sed` from `cygwin` (I hope this does not matter as I am aiming for a cross-platform solution).

**EDIT:** /usr/bin/sed version 4.2.2.

Comment: `echo asdfsomethingasdf | sed 's/\(something\)/\\\1/g'` works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I can't see any problems, your sample works for me, tested with cygwin and also Ubuntu 16.04. Check your sed command with `which sed` and `sed --version`. Your problem occours only with normal quotes `echo asdfsomethingasdf | sed -- "s/\(something\)/\\\1/g"`

Comment: The used tags are ambiguous. Batch-file is dos/windows. In case this is the environment change the single quotes to double ones.

Comment: @fancyPants yes this works fine from the cygwin command line, but not from executing a batch file. @jeb double quotes do not change the behaviour. It is probably a strange behaviour of `sed` within the execution of `.bat` files?

Comment: Cygwin in Windows cmd matters. Try to use "\\\\" instead of "\\".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Windows` cmd with `Cygwin`, use this `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\(something\)/\\\\\1/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, four slashes actually work. Is there a cross-platform solution? I need the file to be double-clickable on Windows and also working from terminal on Mac/Linux.

Comment: `Windows` cmd unescape all '\' automatically, so maybe if you wrap this sed command in bash script and launch it from cmd, as: 'c:\bla\bla>sh -c "my_bash_with_sed.sh"', there is a chance that would work (if sh.exe is installed with cygwin).

Comment: @Martin You can try without single quotes: `sed -e s/\\(something\\)/\\&/` as a POSIX shell will expand \\ to \ when it's not in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your script from a batch file

**myBatch.bat**

```
@echo off
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash ./mySed
```

**mySed**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo asdfsomethingasdf | sed 's/\(something\)/\\\1/g'
```

It can be necessary to use `/usr/bin/sed` when your path isn't completely set